# Cross-platform audio import from different sources

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming

I am using Python, and I want to analyze audio files from internet streaming media (for example Youtube, Soundcloud, etc.)
Is there a universal way to do so? There is a pre-loading for every music or video, there must be a way to access it? How?
I want to run this script on an external server, that might be relevant to the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All sound you "hear" on your pc has to run through your soundcard, Maybe somehow write a script that "records" the sounds runnning through the device. Maybe u can use Pymedia module?

Comment: That's the idea, I guess I have to take control over the driver of wherever the sound goes through. But would it work on a remote server?

Comment: In fact that wouldn't work for me, as I am trying to get this sound as quickly as possible (I can't afford waiting for the song to be finished loading).